# How do you change the format of the CPagination Pager in YII?

Tags: yii, pager

Be default it has the format:

```
PREV 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 NEXT
```

I want something like:

```
FIRST PREV 1 2 3 .. 7 ... 566 567 568 NEXT LAST
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can. It's actually put out by default, but default Yii CSS hides those items. If you look at this comment and check on the CLinkPager page, you'll see you can control the label as well:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLinkPager#c1893

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! But how do you change the format to show ... ?